# C# ASP.NET storing and looping elements in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

I am trying to store 365 days and each day will have to properties to hold such as a constant number that will decrease by certain operations carried on by functions (it starts with 45 then decreases) and names of people that have a running reservation on that day.
I am using C# and SQL Server...this is done for an ASP application.

The question is: what is the best way to store this information in the database and loop through it? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I come from JAVA background so all am thinking is everyday as an object and having these properties there as arrays and constants for some. then access them to modify then store. but am not sure if that will work with SQL server (i know i can create the same object in c#). So each time i iterate over the collection I would be accessing then editing and finally writing.

Comment: yes, i would suggest first make a class with the properties you want(be careful with the access modifiers in your case..i am guessing you don't want everyone to have access to those constants and properties).Then you might use the persistence storage of a SQL Server to write.I think in your case if you do this in the SQL Server , it could easily result in a lot of database calls very soon.Go ahead implement the class ,post it back here and i am sure, we will solve your problem. :)

Comment: but how can I store an object in SQL? is that even possible?

Comment: u can persist it using any ORM Layer ..Entity Framework(Code first) , n-hibernate (Both of which are too heavy for this job anyway,but u might want to look into them.) Map each property to a column in the database etc. but none of this is actually useful to you if you don't have the class first.